# How large a part of the corona-virus is coding?

Tags: bioinformatics, virology, coronavirus

If you find an example of a sequenced string of coronavirus it is about 30.000 long. Looking for example here https://nextstrain.org/ncov/europe you'll see that by far the largest part of this is actually coding. But is that because that is the entire strain or is it because they are only showing the ORF-part? If the latter is the case how large is the non-coding part then compared to the coding part?

Comment: 30Kb is the total length of the genome, including non-coding regions.

Comment: And I think the reason why it's not easy to find a % of non-coding region(s) stated for almost any virus is that it's not very certain how much is actually non-coding given all the "tricks" (non-canonical translation) viruses use https://www.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/jgv/10.1099/vir.0.042499-0

Comment: Viral genomes are, in general, mostly coding - often in multiple ORFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about 92% of the RNA that is protein-coding. ORF10 is not coding according to newer results, see e.g. [Jungreis, Sealfon, and Kellis (2021)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22905-7). The article is about identifying protein-coding ORFs and distinguishing them from non-coding ones.